# Encrypted ubuntu missing 20.04 full drive encryption

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption

**Summary**

I can't boot back into ubuntu after shutting down my machine (by holding the power button after completing updates).

I originally installed ubuntu a few months ago with full disk encryption during the [installation steps](https://onlinehelp.opswat.com/metaaccess/cryptsetup_-_How_to_encrypt_full-disk_while_installation.html)

I have a running version of Ubuntu Live USB.

I can see my 240 GB SSD drive with the ubuntu existing a `/dev/sda` by doing `sudo lsblk`.

I can't access the data inside it (which may be because I installed it with Full Disk Encryption).

When I run `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda myvol`, I get `Device /dev/sda is not a valid LUKS device`

When I run `pvscan` I get `No matching physical volumes found`

When I run `vgscan` nothing happens.

When I open `GParted`, I get a pop up saying `Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Input/output error`

**How can I check if the data is still there/ recoverable / can I boot into my drive?**

I don't have a backup of my data, but I know the password to the encryption. I would like to download my data before I format the drive.

**Why I had to shut down my machine**: I was running ubuntu. I completed an update, and it asked me to restart, but I was holding off. Google chrome then became unresponsive. It said kill Google Chrome / Wait. I clicked click, 10 seconds later, the same dialog box appeared, and continued showing (I.e. nothing was killing Google chrome, I tried at least 20 times). Shutdown also didn't work, so I held the power button for 10 seconds to shut it down. When I restarted, I'm in the GRUB minimal and no longer can boot into ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that my SSD with ubuntu was corrupted. The reason I could get the GNU grub was because I had the GRUB loader installed on another SSD, and it could not reference the broken SSD with ubuntu.